# Fancy Effects on MKMapOverlay CGPath

Tags: ios, path, mkmapview, overlay

I'm using a MKOverlayView for drawing a path onto the apple maps. I'd like to draw many short paths onto it, because I need to colorize the track depending on some other values. But I'm getting some fancy effects doing it that way ... also my start- and ending points are connected, but I don't know why. After zooming in/out the fancy-effect-pattern changes and gets bigger/smaller. It seems that you can see the apple map tiles on my path ...

This is my code, its called inside the drawMapRect method of my overlay view.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tdpoints.pointCount-1; i++ ){
    CGPoint firstCGPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:tdpoints.points[i]];
    CGPoint secCGPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:tdpoints.points[i+1]];

    if (lineIntersectsRect(tdpoints.points[i], tdpoints.points[i+1], clipRect)){            

        double val1 = (arc4random() % 10) / 10.0f;
        double val2 = (arc4random() % 10) / 10.0f;
        double val3 = (arc4random() % 10) / 10.0f;


        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, val1 ,val2, val3, 1.0f);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);

        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context,firstCGPoint.x,firstCGPoint.y);

        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, secCGPoint.x, secCGPoint.y);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGContextClosePath(context);

    }
}
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/iossimulatorbildschirmf.jpg/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/iossimulatorbildschirmf.jpg/

**I'm adding my GPS Points like that. (From Breadcrumbs Apple Example)**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude = 49.1,.longitude =12.1f}; 
[self drawPathWithLocations:coord];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = {.latitude = 49.2,.longitude =12.2f}; 
[self drawPathWithLocations:coord1];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = {.latitude = 50.1,.longitude =12.9f}; 
[self drawPathWithLocations:coord2];
```

**This is the adding Method:**

```
-(void) drawPathWithLocations:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord{
if (!self.crumbs)
{

    // This is the first time we're getting a location update, so create
    // the CrumbPath and add it to the map.
    //
    _crumbs = [[CrumbPath alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:coord];
    [self.trackDriveMapView addOverlay:self.crumbs];

    // On the first location update only, zoom map to user location
    [_trackDriveMapView setCenterCoordinate:coord zoomLevel:_zoomLevel animated:NO];

}   else
{
    // This is a subsequent location update.
    // If the crumbs MKOverlay model object determines that the current location has moved
    // far enough from the previous location, use the returned updateRect to redraw just
    // the changed area.
    //
    // note: iPhone 3G will locate you using the triangulation of the cell towers.
    // so you may experience spikes in location data (in small time intervals)
    // due to 3G tower triangulation.
    //

    MKMapRect updateRect = [self.crumbs addCoordinate:coord];

    if (!MKMapRectIsNull(updateRect))
    {

        // There is a non null update rect.
        // Compute the currently visible map zoom scale
        MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = (CGFloat)(self.trackDriveMapView.bounds.size.width / self.trackDriveMapView.visibleMapRect.size.width);
        // Find out the line width at this zoom scale and outset the updateRect by that amount
        CGFloat lineWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(currentZoomScale);
        updateRect = MKMapRectInset(updateRect, -lineWidth, -lineWidth);
        // Ask the overlay view to update just the changed area.
        [self.crumbView setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:updateRect];
    }
}
```

**This is the addCoordinate method:**

```
    - (MKMapRect)addCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord
{
   pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwLock);

    // Convert a CLLocationCoordinate2D to an MKMapPoint
    MKMapPoint newPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord);
    MKMapPoint prevPoint = points[pointCount - 1];

    // Get the distance between this new point and the previous point.
    CLLocationDistance metersApart = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(newPoint, prevPoint);

    NSLog(@"PUNKTE SIND %f METER AUSEINANDER ... ", metersApart);

    MKMapRect updateRect = MKMapRectNull;

    if (metersApart > MINIMUM_DELTA_METERS)
    {
        // Grow the points array if necessary
        if (pointSpace == pointCount)
        {
            pointSpace *= 2;
            points = realloc(points, sizeof(MKMapPoint) * pointSpace);
        }    

        // Add the new point to the points array
        points[pointCount] = newPoint;
        pointCount++;

        // Compute MKMapRect bounding prevPoint and newPoint
        double minX = MIN(newPoint.x, prevPoint.x);
        double minY = MIN(newPoint.y, prevPoint.y);
        double maxX = MAX(newPoint.x, prevPoint.x);
        double maxY = MAX(newPoint.y, prevPoint.y);

        updateRect = MKMapRectMake(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
    }

    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwLock);

    return updateRect;
}
```

**Hint**

I think my refresh algorithm only refreshes one tile of the whole map on the screen and because every time the drawMapRect method is called for this specific area a new random color is generated. (The rest of the path is clipped and the oder color remains ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fancy effects" you see are a combination of the way MKMapView calls drawMapRect and your decision to use random colours every time it is draw. To speed up display when the user pans the map around MKMapView caches tiles from your overlay. If one tile goes off screen it can be thrown away or stored in a different cache or something, but the ones still on screen are just moved about and don't need to be redrawn which is good because drawing might mean a trip to your data supply or some other long calculation. That's why you call `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect`, it only needs to fetch those tiles and not redraw everything.

This works in all the apps I've seen and is a good system on the whole. Except for when you draw something that isn't going to be the same each time, like your random colours. If you really want to colour the path like that then you should use a hash or something that seems random but is really based on something repeatable. Maybe the index the point is at, multiplied by the point coordinate, MD5ed and then take the 5th character and etc etc. What ever it is it must generate the same colour for the same line no matter how many times it is called. Personally I'd rather the line was one colour, maybe dashed. But that's between you and your users.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation :) I won't use random colors later on, so the problem will be solved. But im iterating through all my points every time a map rect is drawn. I should find some logic to avoid this ...

Comment: Is there any reason you're not creating an MKPolyline and letting the map view do the rest?

Comment: I will read about MKPolylines, maybe this would be a better solution ... but I don't know the difference between a ployline and CGPath yet.  Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

because whenever you draw any path you need to close it. and as you close the path it automatically draws line between lastPoint and firstPoint.

just remove last line in your path drawing

```
CGContextClosePath(context);
```

Comment: Because of that I added the CGContextClosePath line which is called for every small path "segment".

Comment: you dont need to to that, add all the points one bye one and let your path open dont close it everytime. as i think. if you can post your points array here, then i can check with my project.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `CGContextClosePath` is to literally close the path - connect start and end points.  You don't need that, `StrokePath` drew the path already.  Remove the line.  Also move `CGContextStrokePath` outside your loop, the approach is to move/add line/move/add line... and then stroke (you can change colors as you do this, which you are).

For the "fancy effects" (tilted line joining), investigate the effects of possible `CGContextSetLineJoin` and `CGContextSetLineCap` call parameters.

Comment: Hey, I deleted the CGContextClosePath line, but none of my two problems was solved. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: And did you also use CGContextSetLineJoin?

Comment: If I move CGContextStrokePath outside the loop, no path is drawn. But I'll have a closer look at CGContextSetLineCap/CGContextSetLineJoin.

Comment: Ok, still couldn't find a solution to the "fancy tile effect". But why is drawMapRect called so often ...